# How can I edit a blog specific sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, sidebar

Website I'm referring to: http://www.csolsinc.com/blog/

The sidebar on this page is different than the non-blog pages on the website. I've looked around the coding (it's a Wordpress site), and I'm not entirely sure where to locate how to edit the code specifically in that sidebar?

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to SO! External links are not very convinient, the content tends to change in time. Provide a screenshot, what sidebar you are asking about.

Comment: The side bar below the "Resources" section is located in the <body><div id="wrapper"><div id="content"><div id="sidebar">. You might want to edit this in your server side code?

Comment: You can check what css files are used for the element: in Chrome, press `Ctrl - Shift - I` to inspect the element (sidebar is .page-id-654 #sidebar from [style.css](http://www.csolsinc.com/wp-content/themes/csols/style.css)). @Patrick: yes, I think the question is about template in Wordpress

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking. What exactly are you trying to edit? Add/ modify widgets to the sidebar or change the style?

Answer (score 0):

The code specific to the single blog posts resides in the `single.php` file of the theme. Look for something similar to `get_sidebar()` in that file.

If you're talking about the actual blog archive page, the code can be found in the `page.php` file of your theme.

If you're looking to add/remove widgets to the sidebar, login to the site backend and navigate to `Appearance` > `Widgets`.